# Заполнение ListView C# из List<string[]> wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

У меня на форме есть пустой ListView который будет заполняться каждый раз неизвестным зарание количеством колонок и строк.

xaml для создания ListView у меня следующий:

```
<ListView Name="OptimisationResultsTable" MouseDoubleClick="OptimisationResultsTable_MouseDoubleClick"/>
```

Имена колонок я получаю как `List<string>`
 Сами строки я получаю как `List<string[]>`

Я намериваюсь програмко создать колонки но не пойму как их сбиндить с List ?

Comment: Как по мне вариант с динамическими колонками это то еще извращение. Лучше сделать четкие данные с четкой структурой и четким видом, но динамически - как по мне это лень в создание структурированных данных. Ну если так хочется, то делайте что то вроде [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643545/wpf-mvvm-how-to-bind-gridviewcolumn-to-viewmodel-collection).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Иначе не получается Мне нужно отображать просто каждый раз разные параметры, они не от меня зависят а от объекта отправляющего их на отображение. Быть может как то через Table можно сделать ?

Comment: Я вам показал как это делается. А данные, ну извините, я считаю что всегда можно сделать четко понятные объекты, а не динамику.

Comment: Пару бы примеров на изменение колонок. Что-то я сильно сомневаюсь, что нельзя придумать класс, который бы воспроизводил все необходимые колонки.

Comment: Благодарю всех за советы. В итоге сделал через DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

В решении помогла вот эта [ссылка](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7f970a6b-d677-419e-a4e6-173900bb87b1/how-to-bind-wpf-listview-to-datasettable-using-code?forum=wpf):

Вот что получилось (демка)
xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TestEmptyLV.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestEmptyLV"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Fill In"/>

        <ListView MouseDoubleClick="ListView_MouseDoubleClick" Name="LV" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Data;

namespace TestEmptyLV
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            LV.DataContext = tb;
        }

        DataTable tb = new DataTable();

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tb.Rows.Clear();
            tb.Columns.Clear();
            tb.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col1")
            {
                DataType = typeof(string)
            });
            tb.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col2")
            {
                DataType = typeof(string)
            });

            tb.Rows.Add(tb.NewRow());
            tb.Rows[0]["Col1"] = "Hellow";
            tb.Rows[0]["Col2"] = "World";

            tb.Rows.Add(tb.NewRow());
            tb.Rows[1]["Col1"] = "Hellow";
            tb.Rows[1]["Col2"] = "World twice";

            GridView gv = new GridView();

            foreach (DataColumn item in tb.Columns)
            {
                GridViewColumn gv_col = new GridViewColumn
                {
                    Header = item.ColumnName,
                    DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(item.ColumnName)
                };

                gv.Columns.Add(gv_col);
            }

            LV.View = gv;

            LV.Items.Refresh();
        }

        private void ListView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (LV.SelectedItem is DataRowView rowView)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} {1}", rowView.Row["Col1"], rowView.Row["Col2"]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Очень сочувствую вам и очень советую научится делать привязки и работать с ними, иначе, WPF вам не нужен, ибо 90% его особенностей вы не поймете и не будете использовать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Так я и использую привязки. Мне просто нужно отображать различные столбцы, подскажите как иначе Вы это сделаете ? 
Наиболее простой пример который мне нужно реализовать (это не то что я делаю но что бы не вдаваться в подробности) - это загрузка файла у которого данные разбиты по столбцам и его отображение в ListView. Т.е. один файл имеет к примеру 5 столбцов и 10 строк а другой 15 строк и 2 столбца. кол - во столбцов может быть неограниченно велико. Вот что то в этом духе мне и нужно. Попробуйте это иначе реализовать ? Если подскажите более простой и красивый способ то я только за.

Comment: `я и использую привязки` - то, что вы используете, это создание контролов через код, в WPF с его привязками такое делать странно. Я вижу, что вы новичок в WPF, по этому просто совет. Старайтесь не работать с контролами из кода, уберите `Name="LV"` из XAML и попробуйте сделать нормальными привязками все это. Научитесь, там уже будет не далеко и до MVVM и куча всего еще полезного. Но сейчас ваш подход на уровне WinForms и в будущем вы просто поймете, что изобрели кучу костылей и все у вас не так быстро работает. `Вы это сделаете ?` - я вам уже это давно сделал, первым же комментарием к вопросу.

Comment: Ок поизучаю повнимательнее попозже ту ссылку быть может заменю свой код.

Comment: Я бы в данном случае вместо ListView использовал DataGrid с AutoGenerateColumns=True. Этот велосипед изобретён уже давно.